# how to rearrange the order of dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm facing a problem where I want to rearrange the order of dictionary keys. I have an array which has `env = [key1, key2, key3]` and then in a loop these keys are being fetched from array and fed to a dictionary; **dict_result**. 
dic_result shows the order of these env keys in dictionary in below format(based on alphabetical order of the names of key1, key2, 3 even though i didn't use any sorted function):

```
{'name': {'key2': [val1, val2, val3], 'key1': [], 'key3': [val1, val2]},
'name1': {'key2': [val1, val2, val3], 'key1': [], 'key3': [val1, val2]},
...
}

for k in dict_result['name'].keys():
    //performing checks
```

I want to change the order of nested keys for dict_result[name]to look like :

```
{'name': {'key3': [val1, val2]}, 'key2': [],'key1': [val1, val2, val3]}
```

I did give a try using inbuilt function reversed() but it seems to create an iterator which change quite some logic in my existing code and for loop that is iterating over these dictionary env keys and performing checks/validations based on its values. 
I now understand that a regular dict doesn’t track the insertion order, and iterating it gives the values in an arbitrary order.

Kindly help if there is an easier way to either have dictionary consume the env keys exactly in the same order they are being fed/ingested from array i.e. key1, key2, key 3 or just can reverse it to have key3, key 2, key1. 
But don't want the existing way it is showing alphabetical order based on the actual key names.

Comment: do you want to sort these keys alphabetically? Keep in mind (depending of the Python version you are using) that dicts are not sorted (before Python 3.6), and after Python 3.6 the order of insertion is kept.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf that dicts are not sorted (before Python 3.6), and after Python 3.6 the order of insertion is kept. i didn't get this,Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @NarendraLucky, before Python 3.6 the order of the elements in dictionaries was not relevant, by order I mean insertion order. You can read more about in [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/51te8x/raymond_hettingerpython36_news_ordereddict_is/). Also, in Python 3.6 insertion order was not totally guaranteed, it was since Python 3.7 that [you can rely on this feature](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).

Comment: i updated the description after narrowing down issue I'm noticing; does it help?

Answer (score 2):

[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) could be used to maintain the insertion-ordering, once the keys are sorted.

```
import collections

data = {'name': {'key3': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [], 'key1': [5, 6]}}
data['name'] = sorted(data['name'].items())
order_dict = collections.OrderedDict(data)
print(order_dict)
```

O/P:

```
OrderedDict([('name', [('key1', [5, 6]), ('key2', []), ('key3', [1, 2, 3])])])
```

Comment: Using OrderedDict worked for me . But I didn't have to use sorted. This is what I did:
 
    import collections
    
    dict_result['name']= collections.OrderedDict()

Answer (score 1):

An one-liner dictionary-comprehension:

```
print({k: dict(zip(list(v.keys())[::-1], list(v.values())[::-1])) for k, v in dict_result.items()})
```

This works for any amount of keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could update this particular dictionary:

```
dict_result['name'] = {key: dict_result['names'][key] for key in sorted(dict_result['name'].keys())}
```

Comment: @U10-Forward, that is good point. Actually I just focused in this particular case since the person who asked the question didn't mentioned about it. Btw, I liked your answer, but I feel it could be a bit hard to read for a newbie.

Comment: Yeah that's right i am making the shortest possible solution that i can think of

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dictionary=OrderedDict()
for i in (old_dict.keys()):
    my_dictionary[i]=b[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `reversed()` keyword, you can get your result:-

```
val1,val2,val3 = 1,2,3
dict_result = {'name': {'key3': [val1, val2, val3], 'key2': [], 'key1': 
 [val1, val2]}}
old_key = dict_result['name'].keys()
old_key = list(old_key)
new_key = list(reversed(old_key))
#print(new_key)
value = []
for k in new_key:
    value.append(dict_result['name'][k])
zip_key_value = list ( zip(new_key, value) )
temp_dict = dict(zip_key_value)
new_dict_result = {'name':temp_dict}

print(dict_result)
print(new_dict_result)
```

**Output**

```
{'name': {'key3': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [], 'key1': [1, 2]}}
{'name': {'key1': [1, 2], 'key2': [], 'key3': [1, 2, 3]}}
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks @rahul-charan , I already give this a try but it seems I'll have to change my rest of the code logic as reversed() converts the keys of 'name' to an iterator, not sure what happens to the individual values of key1, key2, key3 keys.How can I access key1 values now? The new dictionary becomes `dict_result =
{'name': <listreverseiterator object at 0x10c3f7fd0>} `
  Surely, when printed after reversed(), list(dic_result[app]) does reverse the keys as [key1, key2, key3 ].

Comment: @anonymous-explorer I think I have got your point, I have changed my code see it, maybe it helps you